# How can I get multiple entity in one Cypher query with spring-data-neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In one query I want to give a pagination to have a limit return nodes (ex: 50 records) but I want count total number of nodes (ex:200) to do the pagination.

I use TimeTree with the same in this post https://www.graphgrid.com/modeling-time-series-data-with-neo4j/. I want to get all user that birth between to date.

This is my query :

```
MATCH (t:TimeLine)-[:HAS_YEAR]->(fromYear:Year{value:{year}})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(fromMonth:Month{value:{month})-[:HAS_DAY]->(fromDay:Day{value:{day}})-[:NEXT_DAY*0..10000]->(middleDay:Day)<-[:BIRTH_ON]-(u:User)
WITH count(u) as c
MATCH (t:TimeLine)-[:HAS_YEAR]->(fromYear:Year{value:{year}})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(fromMonth:Month{value:{month}})-[:HAS_DAY]->(fromDay:Day{value:{day}})-[:NEXT_DAY*0..10000]->(middleDay:Day)<-[:BIRTH_ON]-(u:User)
return u, c
```

Separate it to 2 queries may be easier but server will send 2 requests to database. I test my query and the result is it take 2 times longer.

Get all the nodes and do the pagination in server may be better but the transfer data is too big if I have large number of nodes.

I don't have any idea with this problem

Comment: The Cypher query looks fine, as far as I can tell. Do you see any problems if you PROFILE the query?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yeah. I have a TimeLine and I want to get all user between to date: MATCH (t:TimeLine)-[:HAS_YEAR]->(fromYear:Year{value:{year}})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(fromMonth:Month{value:{month})-[:HAS_DAY]->(fromDay:Day{value:{day}})-[:NEXT_DAY*0..10000]->(middleDay:Day)<-[:BIRTH_ON]-(u:User)
WITH count(u) as c. This query run very slow. If I run it one again to get Users it take me double time

Comment: Can you update your description with this new information? Also, as you seem to be building a timetree, have you looked at the [GraphAware Neo4j TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree)? It is a mature addon, and has procedures for quickly obtaining events within a range.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I updated the description. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @gianglaodai  how did u do this..?